# CDK virtual scroll does not hold the values/state

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, multi-select, angular-cdk

I have added dropdown/select component which has multiple records more than 1500 items. So for obvious reason whenever clicked it used to take significant amount of time to render the items( not more than a second but it was visible lag).

To solve this, I thought of adding mat-option under virtual scroll, which solved the problem, however since I was using multi-select in the drop down, whenever an item is checked and user scroll below to select other time, the selection above loses its state and get unselected.

I was expecting it should be keeping its selected/checked state.